# Load colours from file according to theme

Tags: android, colors, android-theme

My app shows loads of messages from the server and the type of message determines what colour span is applied to it. I already have a dark theme for my app and now I want to add a light theme but the colours for the dark theme can't be re-used as the messages become unreadable against a white background.

At the moment, I have the colours stored in the following RGB format in an xml file under /values:

```
<integer-array name="xyz_message_type">
    <item>001</item> <!--Red-->
    <item>002</item> <!--Green-->
    <item>003</item> <!-Blue-->
</integer-array>
```

and the appropriate colour is selected by passing the R.array.xyz_message_type value to a dedicated class which retrieves and parses the colour.

What would be the easiest way to alter my app to load a 'light' set of colours when the theme is changed? If my approach can be improved, what would be a better way to handle this?

Comment: A little OT, but why use integer-array instead of built-in Color Resources (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)?

Comment: It's done for ease of editing. Using RGB, I can fire up something like MS Paint and tweak the colours to my liking. I also find having separate RGB values more readable than #rrggbb, which doesn't really tell me how 'strong' each of the colours are.